# How do I solve a complex identity

Tags: complex-numbers

So I was solving a problem until I got to the point where I had $$(z-1)^4=(z+1)^4$$ (The question was find $z$ that satisfies that equality) 
I tried to solve it as if both sides are real numbers (I know they aren't but it was just intuitive) and my teacher told me it was wrong. 
I can see that $0$ is a solution, however that doesn't help since its raised to the 4th so I'd expect 3 solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: Let $w=(z-1)/(z+1)$ and solve for $w$ first.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the identity $a^{2}-b^{2}=\left(a-b\right)\left(a+b\right)$ twice

$$0=\left(z+1\right)^{4}-\left(z-1\right)^{4}=\left(\left(z+1\right)^{2}-\left(z-1\right)^{2}\right)\left(\left(z+1\right)^{2}+\left(z-1\right)^{2}\right)=$$

$$=\left(z+1-z+1\right)\left(z+1+z-1\right)\left(2z^{2}+2\right)=8z(z^{2}+1)$$

Comment: Definitely easier than other methods here

Comment: I am so slow at typing, was adding this only :) +1

Comment: Oh yes thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have $$(z-1)^4=(z+1)^4$$ $$\implies z^4-4z^3+6z^2-4z+1=z^4+4z^3+6z^2+4z+1$$ $$\implies 8z^3+8z = 0$$ $$\implies 8z(z^2+1)=0 \implies z= \, ?$$

Answer (score 2):

What you have got is $\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^4=1$. Now $x^4=1$ has got $4$ roots in $\Bbb{C}$, namely $\pm1,\pm i$. Equate $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ to each of these, and you will get the $4$ different values for $z$.

Comment: For $x=1$ you get no solution for $z$. But $x=-1,\pm i$ yields a solution. :-) But I like your way!

Comment: Abishanka: one value that is $z = 1$ which we get from $x = -1$ will be rejected. So $3$ values. This is clear from other answers which expand the expression (ie a cubic).

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
(z-1)^4=(z+1)^4\Leftrightarrow z^4-4z^3+6z^2-4z+1=z^4+4z^3+6z^2+4z+1\\\Leftrightarrow 0=8z^3+8z=8z(z^2+1)=8z(z+i)(z-i).
$$